# Number of ways to sum n numbers to k with restrictions

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming, backtracking

I am struggling to find a DP recursion for the following problem:
Given `N intervals of consecutive positive numbers` and `M`, find how many possibilities of summing n numbers (one from each interval) from n given intervals to k exist.

for instance:

```
n = 2, k = 4
where the n intervals are:
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 2]
```

so there is only one valid solution (2 + 2).

I'm looking for a bottom-up approach.
This is what i've tried:

```
long getPossibilities(int N, int M, vector<vector<int>> &limits) {
vector<vector<long>> dp (N, vector<long>(M + 1, 0));

for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for(int k = limits[i][0]; k <= limits[i][1]; k++){
        dp[0][k] = 1;
    }
}

for(int i = 1; i < N; i++) {
    for(int j = 1; j <= M; j++) {
        dp[i][j] = dp[i - 1][j];
        for(int k = limits[i][0]; k <= limits[i][1]; k++) {
            if(j - k >= 0) {
                dp[i][j] = (dp[i][j] + dp[i][j - k]) % 1000000007;
            }
        }
    }
}
return dp[N - 1][M];
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If you have an array `A[i][j]` representing the number of ways to sum to `i` with the first `j` ranges, and the `j+1`st range is from `a` to `b`, then you have the relation:

```
A[i][j+1] = sum(A[x][j] for x = i-a to i-b)
```

(treating out of bounds reads as 0's).

This update step risks taking O(M^2) time if `b-a` is large, and this is probably why you solution is timing out. You can avoid that by computing cumulative sums first: let `B[i][j] = sum(A[i'][j] for i'=0 to i)`.

Then `A[i][j+1] = B[i-a][j] - B[i-b-1][j]` (*)

The process would be:

1. start with `A[i][0] = 1` if `i=0`, else `1`
2. set `j=0`
3. Compute `B[i][j]` for each `i` from 0 to `M` by summing up elements of `A[_][j]`.
4. Compute `A[i][j+1]` for each `i` from 0 to `M` using the equation (*).
5. Increment `j` until `j=n+1`.
6. Go back to step 3.

When you've finished, `A[M][n]` is the result.

If you're clever you can probably use a single array of size `M` rather than two arrays of size `M` by `n`.

Comment: Thank you. I'm still getting wrong answers for some tests. When I try to print A, it turns out the right answer for those tests and those only (which would be like 10/45) is on A[M+1][N] if I run one extra step. Do you have any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that all interval entries are positive. One dynamic programming approach is to represent state as `(n, t)` where `n` is the index of current interval and `t` is the target sum. For example, the initial state in your example is `n=0` and `t=4`.

Let `f(n, t)` denote the number of ways in which we can choose one element from interval `n` till the last s.t. the sum of chosen elements is `t`. Then, in pseudocode,

```
f(n, t) = sum(f(n+1), t - row[n][j]) for j <= len(row[n]))
```

Here is one possible implementation using Python; the `naive` function` is included to check for correctness (assumes that all intervals are of the same length).

```
def naive(xs, target):
  from itertools import product
  res = 0
  for tup in product(*xs):
    res += sum(tup) == target
  return res 

def one_per_row_sums(xs, target):
  n = len(xs)
  if n == 0:
    return 0
  m = len(xs[0])
  assert all(len(x) == m for x in xs)

  def f(n, k):
    if k < 0:
      return 0
    if n == 0:
      return sum(1 if x == k else 0 for x in xs[n])
    else:
      return sum(f(n-1, k-j) for j in xs[n])

  return f(n-1, target)

xs = [[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]]
assert naive(xs, 4) == one_per_row_sums(xs, 4)

# larger test
import numpy as np
n = 6
m = 6
xs = np.sort(np.random.randint(0, 10, (n, m)), axis=1)
assert one_per_row_sums(xs, 20) == naive(xs, 20)
```

Comment: This actually is the first approach I tried. However, I get a time limit exceeded warning. This is why I am looking for a bottom-up aproach. My recursion formula is dp[i][j] = dp[i-1][j] + j >= k ? dp[i][j - k] : 0; where i is n (level), j is current target and k is current element in xs. But I don't think I got it right.

Comment: You may want to update your question with the full problem statement (including modus calculations) and the code you have tried so far.